# How to get event props in React component with rest operator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I need some help. I am beginner in TS and i don't know how can i use my event props in my component. I defined two props and i need all my events as rest props.

I got an error when i use my component with onClick event.

Error: Property 'onClick' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ButtonProps'

I will be grateful for any help you can provide.

Here is my component:

```
export type ButtonProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  className: string;  
};


export const Button = ({ children, className, ...rest }: ButtonProps) => {
  return (
   <button className={className} {...rest}>
     {children}
   </button>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this using `PropsWithChildren`:

```
import { PropsWithChildren } from "react";

export type ButtonProps = {
  className: string;  
};


export const Button = ({ children, className, ...rest }: PropsWithChildren<ButtonProps>) => {
  return (
   <button className={className} {...rest}>
     {children}
   </button>
  );
};
```

Comment: Maybe i do it wrong, but when i use onClick in my component it says that onClick does not exist on type in my ButtonProps:
<Button className="" children="" onClick={() => {}} />